# How to copy a file to an invisible partition using the GUI in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) and with GUI, Graphical User Interface,
how can a file be copied to `vfat` Partition 1?

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1
```

Terminal shows 3 partitions:

```
lsblk -e7 -o PTTYPE,FSTYPE,PATH,SIZE

PTTYPE FSTYPE PATH             SIZE
gpt           /dev/nvme0n1   465.8G
gpt    vfat   /dev/nvme0n1p1   512M
gpt    ext4   /dev/nvme0n1p2  93.7G
gpt    ext4   /dev/nvme0n1p3 371.6G
```

GUI shows 2 of 3 above partitions:

```
gpt    ext4   /dev/nvme0n1p2  93.7G
gpt    ext4   /dev/nvme0n1p3 371.6G
```

---

#### Background:

With GUI copy `eicar.com.txt` 68 bytes, fake virus, to

```
PTTYPE FSTYPE PATH             SIZE
gpt    vfat   /dev/nvme0n1p1   512M
```

to test if virus scanner inspects above partition 1 `/dev/nvme0n1p1`.

Using GUI, how to copy a file to an invisible Partition?

---

Responding to [user1686’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1735168/167207) that says:

> “Find out if the partition is currently mounted anywhere.
> (The `lsblk` command would have shown you the mountpoint by default, if you hadn't used `-o`.)”

```
lsblk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
```

GUI, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, `/boot/efi` gives error message:

```
Could not enter folder /boot/efi.
```

If the partition is not yet mounted, use gnome-disks (GUI)

```
sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility
```

While running gnome-disk-utility 42.0 and I click on FAT (32-bit version) — Mounted at `/boot/efi` it gives error message:

```
Could not enter folder /boot/efi.
```

Comment: You can't use the ESP as a user partition!!

Answer (score 0):

Find out if the partition is currently mounted anywhere. (The `lsblk` command would have shown you the mountpoint by default, if you hadn't used `-o`.)

If the partition is already mounted, manually enter its path in your GUI file manager's address bar. (They all have one; often the standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> hotkey or sometimes <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> will activate it.)

If the partition is not yet mounted, use `gnome-disks` (GUI) or `mount` (not GUI) to mount it somewhere, then enter the mountpoint path in your file manager. (In the GNOME Disks app, select the partition and click the "▶" button to mount it; this should also make the partition appear in the file manager automatically.)

Comment: The partition seems to be the ESP.

Comment: Question was updated.